# Attaching a motorized flip down tv mount to my apartment ceiling

Tags: ceiling, joists, hanging, mount

I would like to attach a motorized flip down mount for a 50” tv to my apartment ceiling. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GGR6I24) is the exact mount.
[image: See diagram picture attached]My apartment is a new building that was built 2 years ago.  It was built with post tensioned flat plate cast in place concrete.  I know one part of the ceiling is concrete.  The other another part of the ceiling is made out of an unknown material and dips down 14 inches.. that is ideally where I’d like to attached the mount.

On the diagram to the far left you will see a little cubby that I opened up to see what is in that 14” of ceiling.  I have included 4 of the best pictures I could get.  Do you think this is possible? If so, what do you recommend doing? [image] [image][image][image]

Comment: Someone else might have more info for you, but taking a guess I'd assume that's just a hollow chase to run the ductwork, sprinkler, possibly some other stuff. Without seeing back into the cavity, I'm guessing the center of it will likely only be drywall and there won't be enough structure there to support a tv.

Comment: Do you have power nearby? Do you rent?

Comment: Yes I have power near by and yes I do rent

Answer (score 1):

I like that mount.

It appears your soffit housing the duct work is made of steel studs covered in drywall.

This is a challenge for the weight of large TV, especially a hanging one that moves.

I would mount a Thick, long, wide board to the drywall spanning  3  studs. The board or boards need to be wider than the depth or length of the mounting plate of the the TV mount.

I would use [Toggler anchors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-30-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183849) to attach the board to the studs, the toggle would/must go through the wall of the metal studs, at least 2 if not 3 anchors per stud.

You need to know exactly how the soffit is constructed, **I.E.** where the studs are and make sure you are mounting to them and not just drywall.

Here is good [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2r44N5tvR8) of how to install the toggler toggle anchors.

Once you have a good solid board installed you have something strong enough to mount you TV too.

Before you install your board you should determining where the TV mount will be located and mark the location of the plate and the holes for the mounting bolts on the board.

Since it is a hanging mount i would not use lags or screws but instead i would use machine bolts into [T-nuts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MSVU3WF).  Pre-drill your holes and mount the T-nut on the back side of the board. You will need to size the bolts, washers and T-nuts to work with your TV mount holes.

Here is a good [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVfkxJiqLkA) on T-nuts.

Comment: Good plan, because the steel studs will be prone to flexing under the weight and stress. The only thing is, be prepared to have your landlord insist on a full repair back to original when you leave.

Comment: Would it be easier to mount it to the concrete instead?

Comment: It could be mounted on A concrete ceiling with the proper anchors, would it be easier, that depends on your skills and tools. It also depends on the construction of the concrete ceiling. to mount it on the soffit would require a normal drill and a few drillbits, to mount it on the concrete ceiling would require a hammer drill and masonry bits. If you are a renter then Patching the drywall will be easier than patching the concrete.